# Guardar respuestas correctas e incorrectas para usuario registrado y no Registrado

Tags: php, mysql

En el proyecto de mi juego de mates, el cual es sumar dos numeros de dos cifras.

Quiero guardar cuantas respuestas correctas ha realizado y guardar esa puntuación. si el usuario esta registrado la guardaremos en la bbdd para poder luego visualizarla en su panel de control. Y si es un usuario sin registrar la guardaremos para luego mostrarla por pantalla y si cierra el navegador se borra la sesión.

Como podría guardar los resultados que ha acertado?

A qui tengo mi codio php del juego

```
<?php
/****JUEGO DE MATES****/
//Hemos de realizar lo primero saber si el usuario esta registrado o no
// si esta registrado las variable las guardamos en la bbdd para poder acceder luego y mostrarlo
//si no hemos de hacer sesiones
session_start();
?>

//aqui vendria el juego y guardar las variables en sesiones
<form action="procesar-juego.php" method="POST">
<?php
 $mostrar_tiempo = $_POST['tiemporestante'];
?>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="jueguecillo">
            <tr>
                <th colspan = "3"> SUMA NUMERO DE 2 CIFRAS </th>
                <th>TIEMPO: &nbsp;&nbsp; <span id="count" style="font-size:19px"></span></th>
                <th><button id="empeza" value="" name="EMPEZAR" class="btn btn-success">EMPEZAR</button></th>
            </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:19px">
                        <?php

                        $num1 = rand(10, 99);
                        echo $num1;

                        ?>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num1; ?>" name="num1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="2%" style="font-size:19px">
                        <?php

                        $operacion = "+";

                        echo $operacion;

                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:19px">
                        <?php

                        $num2 = rand(10, 99);
                        echo $num2;

                        ?>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num2; ?>" name="num2"/>
                    </td>

                    <td width="20%">
                        <input type="number" name="resultado" value="" class="span4"/>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <button type="submit" name="validar" value="" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" id="tr" name="tiemporestante" value=""/>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--Por si queremos reiniciar el juego -->
                        <button type="submit" value="reset"  name="reset" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">REINICIAR</button>


                    </td>


                </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Esto es lo visual

La parte de ejecución es la siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST['validar'])){

          $comprobar =  $_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2'];

          if($comprobar == $_POST['resultado']){
              ?>
              <script>
                  alert('¡Has acertado! Sigue que todavía te quedan :<?php     echo $_POST['tiemporestante'] ?> segundos');
              </script>

              <?php


          }else{

              ?>
              <script>
                  alert('Has fallado :(');
              </script>

              <?php



          }



      }
```

Aqui es donde quiero guardar en una variable los resultados que ha acertado. y no se si se podría poner las sumas totales que ha realizado.

Comment: De acuerdo con @Flowen, si quieres que ademas se mantengan cuando vuelva a entrar, aún cerrada la sesion, también podrías usar, en cliente, localStorage para guardar ciertas cosas combinándolo con alguna cookie. Estos datos de borrarían al borrar la cache del navegador.

Comment: Lo que prefiero es que al cerrar el navegador ya no tenga nada guardado.

Comment: Perfecto entonces lo que te ha comentado @flowen es perfecto.

Answer (score -1):

Para guardar el resultado de los usuarios que no estén registrados, puedes utilizar variables de sesión.

No voy a poner código, ya que no has facilitado ninguno. Te dejo un enlace a la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php).

Cuando cierre el navegador, la variable desaparecerá.

**Respondiendo a tu nueva edición:**

Simplemente crea la variable de sesión cuando el usuario acierte la pregunta.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['aciertos'] = 1;
```

Y vas incrementándola según vaya acertando más.

En cuanto a la parte de la base de datos y comprobar si existe el usuario, no tenemos información de ella, por lo que queda en tus manos.

Comment: Vale perfecto, Gracias

Comment: Como distingo si el usuario esta registrado o no?

Comment: Desconozco tu sistema de registros.

Comment: Te explico, esto es para un proyecto que he codigo avanzado, es decir no lo he empezado yo desde cero, la web esta fatalmente hecha, no se ni como esta lo que quiero es hacerlo para una web nueva y luego rehacer la web de juegos bien hecha con un wordpress y demás. Porque la verdad es desastrosa la web.

Comment: He editado la pregunta

Comment: Actualizado @AitorUdabe

Comment: y como hago que se vaya incrementando los aciertos?

Comment: Sumándole 1 a la variable

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer ahora es hacer el juego sin depender de la web es decir tenerlo todo externo para luego hacer la web y ponerlo debido a que ahora esta fatal.

Comment: tal que asi <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['validar'])){
$comprobar =  $_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2'];
if($comprobar == $_POST['resultado']){
$_SESSION['aciertos'] = $_SESSION['aciertos'] + 1;
 ?>

Comment: Exacto @AitorUdabe

Comment: puede darme tu correo quiero hacerte una proposición

Comment: perdona que se me ha caido todo el sisema de internet,

Comment: Te enviado mi correo.